# MATLAB - datetick (specify number of points on axis)

Tags: matlab, date

I use datetick('x','HH:MM:SS.FFF'). How can I specify how many labels (specially denotes points) on the x-axis it puts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetick` replaces the labels of the current tick marks with formatted date/time strings.

You control the actual location of the ticks using [axes properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axes_props.html)

> XTick, YTick, ZTick: vector of data values locating tick marks

```
set(gca,'xtick', [1 4 6]);%sets ticks at x=1, x=4, x=6
```

`gca` is "get current axes", so this will change the xtick locations on the most recent axes you've activated (created, clicked on, or however else).  If you have a `axes handle` to another set of axes, you can use that handle in place of "gca".

Comment: @Trup there was a typo, I added a comma between 'xtick' and the vector of numbers.

Comment: Also, there are a number of options you can give datetick as arguments; check the documentation online.  You can also specify your xtick locations after calling datetick.